# Como puedo insertar datos una sola vez Androidstudio SQLite?

Tags: java, android-studio

tengo el siguiente gestorBD, donde hago selects, etc.

Lo que quiero hacer es introducir una sola vez los datos en la BD.

Ya he intentado varias veces con el getCount como en el ejemplo pero no funciona bien.

Alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo?

Gracias de antemano.

```
package com.example.carlesmiranda.m8_tascagrups;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class gestorBD extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();

    public gestorBD(Context context){
        super (context, "horaris", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE horaris (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, horaSortida TEXT, horaArribada TEXT, sortida TEXT, arribada TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void cargarDatos(){
        guardarHorario("8:00","8:25","Reus", "Tarragona");
        guardarHorario("9:00","9:25","Reus", "Tarragona");
        guardarHorario("10:00","10:25","Reus", "Tarragona");

        System.out.println("HA CARGADO");
    }

    private void guardarHorario(String horaSortida, String horaArribada, String sortida, String arribada) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        guardarHorarios(db, horaSortida, horaArribada, sortida, arribada);
    }

    private void guardarHorarios(SQLiteDatabase db, String horaSortida, String horaArribada, String sortida, String arribada) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("horaSortida", horaSortida);
        cv.put("horaArribada", horaArribada);
        cv.put("sortida", sortida);
        cv.put("arribada", arribada);
        db.insertOrThrow("horaris", null, cv);
    }

    private void comrpobarTabla(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT horaSortida FROM horaris",null);



        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cargarDatos();
            System.out.println("CARGA DATOS "+cursor.getCount());
        }else{
            System.out.println("NO CARGA DATOS "+cursor.getCount());
        }

    }

    public void  obtenerHorarios(String arribadaS, String sortidaS){
        System.out.println("obtenerHorarios1");

        comrpobarTabla();

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM horaris WHERE sortida='"+arribadaS+"' AND arribada='"+sortidaS+"'",null);

        try{
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do{
                    String horaSortida = cursor.getString(1);
                    String horaArribada = cursor.getString(2);
                    String sortida = cursor.getString(3);
                    String arribada = cursor.getString(4);

                    arrayList1.add(horaSortida);
                    arrayList2.add(horaArribada);

                }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }



        }catch (Exception e){
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        db.close();

        System.out.println("obtenerHorarios2");

    }

}
```

Comment: a que te refieres con insertarlos una vez?

Comment: tu tabla se llama `horaris` o `horario`

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez que solo se inserten los datos una vez al inciar la app, no cada vez que entre en la aplicacion, se llama horaris.

Comment: enq ue momento ejecutas la accion de guardarlo que que activity?

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es una vez se inicie la Aplicacion hacer la funcion cargar datos, lo unico que tengo es un MainActivity donde ejecuto el gestorBD, lo que hacia antes era dejar la funcion cargarDatos() y me llenaba la BD y lo que quiero es que al inciar la App se cargen los datos solo una vez (Primer inicio cargar datos, Segundo inicio no cargar datos)

Answer (score 0):

La carga de datos la debes hacer en tu metodo `public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE horaris (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, horaSortida TEXT, horaArribada TEXT, sortida TEXT, arribada TEXT)");
    cargarDatos(db);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void cargarDatos(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO horaris VALUES('8:00','8:25','Reus', 'Tarragona')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO horaris VALUES('9:00','9:25','Reus', 'Tarragona')");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO horaris VALUES('10:00','10:25','Reus', 'Tarragona')");

    System.out.println("HA CARGADO");
}
```

Esto si solo lo cargaras al momento de crear la BD

Answer (score -2):

¿ya intentaste con un "SELECT * FROM"

Seria así

db.execSQL("INSERT INTO horaris 
SELECT '8:00','8:25','Reus', 'Tarragona'
UNION ALL 
SELECT '9:00','9:25','Reus', 'Tarragona'");

Comment: Sugiero que antes de emitir una respuesta que pueda ayudar a la comunidad prueben primero y luego dan un resultado concreto.